# Spring Webflux Reactor context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In the following example, `test2` should be able to access the `context` values from `test` and `test1`, but it seems like that is not happening.

Any insight is welcome.

References:

1. http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context
2. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20239 (formerly SPR-15680)
3. https://simonbasle.github.io/2018/02/contextual-logging-with-reactor-context-and-mdc/.

   ```
   import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
   public class Test {

       public static void main(final String[] args) {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
               + " main "
               + test());
       }

       public static String test() {
           final String key = "message";
           return test1().subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "test")).block();
       }

       public static Mono<String> test1() {
           final String key = "message1";
           return test2().subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "test1 "));
       }

       public static Mono<String> test2() {
           return Mono.just("test2").map(item -> {
               Mono.subscriberContext().map(context -> {
                   System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                       + " test2 "
                       + context);
                   return context;
               });
               return item;
           });
       }}
   ```

Output:

```
main main test2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you wanted to access the subscriber context in the test2(), right? This only works, if you are actually in the same flow, so this snippet would fix the original code:
Original:

```
public static Mono<String> test2() {
    return Mono.just("test2").map(item -> {
        // you're creating a new Mono context here, and don't return it/use it anymore
        Mono.subscriberContext().map(context -> {
            System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " test2 "
                + context);
            return context;
        });
        return item;
    });
```

Fixed (with as few changes as possible, could be beautified):

```
public static Mono<String> test2() {
  return Mono.just("test2").flatMap(item -> { // changed map to flatmap, otherwise would be Mono<Mono<String>> here
    Mono<Context> contextMono = Mono.subscriberContext()
        .map(context -> {
          System.err.println(Thread.currentThread()
                                 .getName() + " test2 " + context);
          return context;
        });
    // let item be returned from "inside" of context Mono
    return contextMono.map(context -> item);
  });
```

I'm pretty much struggeling with the subscribercontext myself all the time - I find it not very clear, when the context was used as intended, and when not. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following code works fine, but still not sure why the code in the question does not work.

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + " main "
            + test());
    }

    public static String test() {
        final String key = "message";
        return test1().subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "test")).block();
    }

    public static Mono<String> test1() {
        final String key = "message1";
        return test2().flatMap(item -> {
            Mono.subscriberContext().map(context -> {
                System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " test1 "
                    + context);
                return context;
            });
            return Mono.just(item);
        }).subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "test1 "));
    }

    public static Mono<String> test2() {
        final String key = "message2";
        return Mono.subscriberContext().flatMap(context -> {
            System.err.println(context);
            return Mono.just("test2");
        }).subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "test2"));
    }

}
```